# Magento 1.9 : When I tap thumbnails it doesn't change main image in mobile view only

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, catalog, slider

When I tap in catalog page thumbnails (different views of products), It must change accordingly, but it shows the same image with url suffix "#" .
It only happens in mobile view, tablet view and in MAC.
It is working fine in Desktop view.
The URL of my website is https://mirakin.com/globe-trotters/europe-2019.html
when I click on thumbnails of any product ,URL changes to https://mirakin.com/globe-trotters/europe-2019.html#
Please help me to resolve it.
I have gone through the flex slider java script.
I am using Magento 1.9[image]

Please mail me to my email id developer@mirakin.com (if possible).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update this code whenever it is :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('header').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('header').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});


To

jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    jQuery('header').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    jQuery('header').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi,thank you so much for you respose,
I have tried to update with the codes ,but it is not working.
I would like to remind that ,in only mobile (small screen) the thumnails tapping doesn't work.
it is working fine in desktop.but not in mobile...

Comment: I have also checked to skin/frontend/rwd/mytheme/js/app.js
I think this file is only responsible for the change,
But when i edited.,i found nothing.
please help me to resolve it.

Comment: As I said earlier , please update that piece of code, whenver you find it. It is issue of jquery and prototype conflict.

Comment: hi,
when i added this piece of code it doesn't work.
is there anything other reason causing this only in mobile view.